# use hive execution hook to retrieve number of rows returned from query?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need to capture the number of rows returned from Hive queries using a post execution hook.  I've been poking around in the HiveHistoryViewer docs and thought the count might be in HiveHistory.QueryInfo.rowCountMap field, but it doesn't appear to be populated when I run test queries in my development environment.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks!